# Using HTML in Fat-Free-Framework .ini files

Tags: php, html, language-translation, fat-free-framework

I use Fat Free Framework with a .ini file languages dictionary.
Now some languages require a different layout or HTML in a translation.

If I use HTML in my .ini file, Fat Free simply (and logically) prints the HTML code instead of the parsed HTML.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
English language:
my_text_block = Go to <a href="something">Something</a> to do something.

Dutch language:
my_text_block = Instead of a href I might want a <ul>here</ul>
```

Should I use another translation setup than .ini files? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F3 automatically escapes every output. To prevent this, you have print the "raw" output like this:

```
{{@my_text_block|raw}}
```

Alternatively, you can set `ESCAPE` to `false` (Default: true) which disables escaping everywhere. I don't really recommend this way though.

See http://fatfreeframework.com/views-and-templates#DataSanitation